# Why does "\\\\" equals "\\" in zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh, ksh

So to write a backslash to `stdout` you do

```
zsh$ echo \\
\
```

You would think that to output 2 backslashes, you need to run this:

```
zsh$ echo \\\\
\
```

**Wrong**, You need 6 or 8:

```
zsh$ echo \\\\\\
\\
zsh$ echo \\\\\\\\
\\
```

**Why on earth would I need 8 backslashes ?**

Behaviors in different shells :

```
ksh$ echo \\\\
\\
zsh$ echo \\\\
\
bash$ echo \\\\
\\
sh$ echo \\\\
\
csh$ echo \\\\
\\
```

[image: Backslashes]

Comment: wrt ```to write a backslash to stdout you do echo \\``` - no, to write a backslash to stdout you do `echo '\'` and to write 2 backslashes is `echo '\\'`. Always single-quote scripts and strings unless you NEED to use double quotes (e.g. to let a variable expand) and then always use double unless you NEED to use none (e.g. to allow globbing). Add the missing quotes, re-run your commands, and then ask if you still have a question.

Comment: @EdMorton OH MY GOD  , I didn't know single quotes were unescapable. I thought single quotes and double quotes were the same. You just saved me a lot of time (and backslashes)

Comment: There are **huge** differences between single vs double quotes and between  quotes vs no quotes. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: ``\\`` and `'\'` are equivalent; quotes are just a shortcut for escaping each character between the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably used to `bash`'s built-in `echo`, which does *not* perform expansion of escape sequences. POSIX `echo`, however, *does*. `zsh` follows the POSIX specification, so when you write  `echo \\\\\\`, here's what happens.

1. Quote removal reduces `\\\\\\` to `\\\`; each escaped `\` becomes a literal `\`.
2. `echo` takes the three `\` it receives, and replaces the first `\\` with `\`. The remaining `\` doesn't precede anything, so it is treated literally.
3. The final result is an output of two `\`.

With `echo \\\\\\\\`, here's what happens.

1. As before, `\\\\\\\\` becomes `\\\\`, because each pair of backslashes becomes a single `\` after quote removal.
2. `echo` takes the 4 backslashes, and replaces the first `\\`  with `\` and the *second* `\\` with `\` as well, since this time it received two matched pairs.
3. The final result is again two `\`.

`bash` probably inherited its non-POSIX comformance from `ksh`, `sh` is by definition a POSIX-comformant shell, and it's best not to think about what `csh` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not only zsh, it's default behavior in terminal, backslash (`\`) is a special character used to tell bash script that you want to other params/texts in newline, so to avoid newline,u need add another backslash to escape special character, since backslash also used for escape special character

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, why does "echo \\\\" outputs "\" in bash and "\\" in zsh ? Or put in another way why do "echo \\\\" and "echo \\" output the same thing in zsh ?

Comment: ah sorry, I missed you question, from zsh doc: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html ,  zsh has its own implement of echo, it added another layer to bash echo, u need -E flag, or the BSD_ECHO option to disable zsh's escape

Comment: since zsh added another layer to bash echo, zsh \\\\ will interpret to bash \\, in bash \\ will interpret as \, that's why you get only \ at the end

Comment: Thanks, I think @EdMorton's comment was what I was looking for. I guess the implementation of `sh` has a similar "issue".